# Synchronized Block underlying implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I've just finished an OS course, which included a large section about concurrency.  Now that I return to Java, I find myself with some questions about Java's synchronization system. Most I was able to look up, but one eluded my grasp.

What kind of locking mechanism is used to implement `synchronized` blocks? I ran a simple test and found that:

```
String s = "Asdf";
synchronized (s) {
  synchronized (s) {
    System.out.println("Got to inner block");
  }
}
```

Runs correctly, so I assume it is not a simple lock or single permit semaphore (which would deadlock upon trying to acquire it twice in a row).

Additionally, in the following example:

```
public class Foo {

    public synchronized void m() {
        System.out.println("m called");
        n();
    }

    public synchronized void n() {
        System.out.println("n called");
        //Do some other stuff...
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo f1 = new Foo();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> f1.m());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> f1.m());
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

Will `t1` (or `t2`, whichever happens to grab the lock first) hold the foo lock throughout its `m()` call, or does it surrender it and then try to re-acquire it when `m()` calls `n()`, given that both `m()` and `n()` are synchronized methods? My guess is the former, but I would like to be certain before I write any code that relies on this assumption.

Comment: Monitor locks in java are reentrant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949145/synchronized-keyword-internal-implementation

Comment: And there's no releasing of the lock between the `m` and `n` calls.