# How can Java achieve to let execute a certain "synchronized" method by ONLY one thread at a time?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock, synchronized

How can JVM allow this? I don't understand it.

My hypothesis is that the all threads that we create are actually behind one single Java thread that manage which and how the behind thread actually executes in the processor. But this way it's like you don't have parallel execution, which I don't think is what happens I guess.

Otherwise, if it's not that(and so the threads are not behind one Java thread, but they are independent), how can two created threads that are for example in that moment at the same time both inside two CPUs and want to access the same method, be aware of it and not access the method? I think there must be something that controls that. How is this synchronization done?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949145/synchronized-keyword-internal-implementation

Comment: Most objects in Java can have locking primitives associated with them. Including class objects. Basically, when you tag an instance-level method with `synchronized`, it works similarly to acquiring and/or waiting for a monitor on the instance that the method belongs to. When you tag a static method, it works similarly as if acquiring and/or waiting for a monitor on the `Class<T>` object this method is declared in.

Comment: Re, "...all threads...are actually...one single Java thread..." Are you suggesting that threads in Java work differently from threads in other programming languages? They don't. In all the major Java implementations, each Java thread is "backed" by its own native thread, and each Java intrinsic lock is backed by its own native "mutex" (or, whatever the OS calls it). If you _really_ want to understand how mutexes can work between threads running on different CPUs, you're going to need a book. https://www.amazon.com/dp/0124159508/ But, ...

Comment: ...The TLDR version is, every multi-CPU hardware architecture has special op-codes that support things like mutexes. The op-codes have names like [_CAS_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap), or [_LL_ and _SC_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional), and the memory system hardware is designed to work with the CPU hardware to ensure that those instructions behave as advertised.